# How to access public property from private and public functions in a JavaScript module?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how to access a public property from private and public functions in a JavaScript module?

For example, if this is my module:

```
var PersonModule = (function(){

    var sayHello = function(){
        alert("Hello " + name);
    }

    var privateChangeNameToBob = function(){
        this.name = "Bob";
    }

    var changeName = function(){
        privateChangeNameToBob();
    }

    return {
        name: "",
        sayHello: sayHello,
        changeName: changeName
    }   
})();
```

Neither `sayHello` or the `changeName` functions work correctly because I don't know how to access the public `name` property. Is there a way to do this? I've worked around it by using private variables with getters and setters, but I'm wondering if I can do it without them.

Comment: Where is name being declared? Is it a global variable? Can you post more of your code in a snippet of jsfiddle so we can get a more complete picture of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a reference to the result object:

```
var PersonModule = (function(){
    function sayHello() {
        alert("Hello " + person.name);
    }
    function privateChangeNameToBob() {
        person.name = "Bob";
    }
    function changeName() {
        privateChangeNameToBob();
    }

    const person = {
        name: "",
        sayHello,
        changeName
    };
    return person;
})();
```

Of course, given your singleton IIFE module, you could just as well refer to `PersonModule.name` directly.

Comment: `sayHello` is still referencing an undefined `name`. It should also be changed to `person.name`.

Answer (score 1):

In the way you're doing it the name variable that you're using as public it's not the same as the one in your sayHello method. You have to understand that this is a MODULE not a class that needs to be instantiated. The IIFE already instantiates it for you. To do what you want you can use the below model. Use `self.` in the public methods/vars and nothing in the private. Then it will all work.

```js
var PersonModule = (function(){
    var self = {};

    var privateChangeNameToBob = function(){
        self.name = "Bob";
    };

    self.sayHello = function(){
        console.log("Hello " + self.name);
    };

    self.changeName = function(){
        privateChangeNameToBob();
    };

    self.name = "";
    
    return self;
})();


PersonModule.name = 'Test';
PersonModule.changeName();
PersonModule.sayHello();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the property inside your closure. Check this example out to understand it better:

```
var ClassName = function(constructorParam) {
 
    var privateProperty = 'Im a private property';
    this.publicProperty = 'Im a public property';
 
    function privateMethod() {
        console.log('Private method');
    }
 
    this.publicMethod = function() {
        console.log('Public method');
        // We can call private properties
        console.log(privateProperty);
        // Either private methods
        privateMethod();
    }
 
}
 
var instance = new ClassName('Here goes something to constructor');
instance.publicMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.name` in `privateChangeNameToBob` is setting `name` as a property of that function, not of the module. You can, instead, use it like so:

```
var PersonModule = (function(){
    var name = '';
    //...
    var privateChangeNameToBob = function(){
        name = "Bob";
    }
    return {
        name: name,
        sayHello: sayHello,
        changeName: changeName
    };
})();
```

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/yv8uqh5y/

One last note is a design pattern you may find useful. You can declare a variable named `base` or similar within your module scope, like so:

```
var PersonModule = (function(){
    var base = {};

    base.name = '';

    base.sayHello = function() {/* ... */};
    //...

    return {
        name: base.name,
        sayHello: base.sayHello,
        changeName: base.changeName
    };
})();
```

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/k63u9bfo/

This way you can reference the base of your module without having to worry what `this` maps to (eg. if you're trying to access the module internally using `this` within an anonymous function declared within a module method.

Comment: Good info, but the `changeName` function still doesn't change the name to "Bob" this way. Do you know why?

Comment: Using `this` in an IIFE will refer to the global object. That's not what you want.

Comment: @jabe I updated my answer. Basically `this` in the context of `changeName` was setting `name` as a property of `changeName`, not of the module.

Comment: The top example in your answer doesn't work at all now that `this` is removed